Extracting ELK Index Log
I have a log in ELK index like below
2024-06-24T05:05:26.31412196Z stdout F {"time": "2024-06-24T05:05:26+00:00", "remote_addr": "-", "x_forwarded_for": "XX.XX.XX.XX, XX.XX.XX.XX", "request_id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx","remote_user": "-", "bytes_sent": 833, "request_time": 0.120, *"status": 401*, "vhost": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com", "request_proto": "HTTP/1.1","path": "/xxxxx/xxxxxxxxx", "request_query": "-", "request_length": 550, "duration": 0.120,"method": "POST", "http_referrer": "-","http_user_agent": "okhttp/4.9.2", "upstream_cache_status": "-" }
The above value is captured in the log.message field. Now, I would like to filter out the log message which status code from 400 to 499. I am unable to write the lucene regex query in ELK.
I have tried the below lucene query
log: "\"status\": 4\*"+", \"vhost\":"
log: "\"status\": 4(\d)+, \"vhost\":"

Has anyone faced this earlier and any suggestion to filter out the value?
Your help is much appreciated. Nothing worked.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Assuming all these logs would take the same format, you could use the following regex pattern:
\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}.*?\{[^}]*"status": 4\d{2}.*\}

This matches an initial date portion of a timestamp, followed by {...}, in which there is a status key:value of 4xx.
Demo
